# How to close the browser window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application, in that I want to close the entire browser on clicking on the close button from our application. I tried with the `window.close()` and `self.close()` functions but they will be closing the browser if the window is opened from `window.open()`.

Please suggest to me how I can close the browser on clicking on the close button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. `window.close()` used to do that in a far past, but browsers don't allow that anymore, going from the concept of that a website should be able to stay open as long as it has to. Eg. a website doesn't end. If you log out, you don't close the window, you simply go back to the home page where you let the user log in again. Same with smartphone apps btw :-)

Comment: Yes I agree, but if I want to close the browser  how can I do that? In my application we have two technologies integrated - cocoa and java web. Cocoa browser is opening the web pages in one portion of the cocoa browser and that portion covered by java web page, by closing the java web page default cocoa web part will appear.

Answer (score 4):

Most modern browsers will only let you close child windows of a parent. You cannot close the parent window through script.

Comment: Even I am thinking like that.